# How to dynamically update ID selector of a button in jQuery's .on() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following piece of code

```
    $('body').on('click', '#break-' + i, function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var NowBreak = moment().format("HH:mm:ss");
        console.log(NowBreak);
    });
```

I'm trying to target an element with an ID which is dynamically generated in the other part of the code via jQuery's `.append()` method. So, I basically append a button with and ID of `break+i` where i is a variable containing some number, but when I try to access it as I do in the code above, it's not working. Why does it not work and how could I fix it? I suppose that I cannot use an expression as attribute with `.on()` method. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your code in jsfiddle which not worked?

Comment: You would be better off using classes to do this.

Comment: Please post the rest of the code.

Comment: Here's jsfiddle of the code https://jsfiddle.net/Jadranka/ovtczav7/

Comment: This seems to work! => [https://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/ovtczav7/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/ovtczav7/2/)

Answer (score 2):

you can try with this code

```
 $('body').on('click', 'div[id^="break-"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var NowBreak = moment().format("HH:mm:ss");
    console.log(NowBreak);
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that target all of the buttons with an ID of "break-" no matter what the variable i holds? I need to target only an instance of a button with an ID that holds a number of current value in variable i.

Comment: in your fiddle where you declare i variable ?

Comment: At the top of the script, before the event handler for the form's submit button and then increment it at the end of the event handler.

Comment: variable i is fixed 0 ?

Comment: can you pls try with  $(document) instead of $('body')

Answer (score 0):

You can set the function directly to the target element using another jQuery selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
$("[id^='break-']").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var NowBreak = moment().format("HH:mm:ss");
    console.log(NowBreak);
});
```